# Update php on Oracle Linux Server

Tags: php, linux, oraclelinux

I have an Oracle Linux Server. I am trying to install PHP. PHP 5.4 installed on OLS. Is there a way to update to php 7.2? When I run `yum install php` it installs version 5.4.

UPDATE
I reinstall linux to ubuntu. There is no any problem on ubuntu

Comment: There is only one tutorial on official site. Its always installs 5.4 version.

Comment: OLS is a fork of RHEL. So with luck something [which works for RHEL](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-php-7-2-on-centos-7-rhel-7/) would also work for OLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo yum install oracle-php-release-el7
sudo yum install php
```

See also: https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-php.html

Comment: Hi, i reinstall os to ubuntu. I can not check it, thanks for answer.